# How to find previously installed apps after micro sdcard gone bad?

Tags: google-play-store, external-sd, google-account

My micro sd card that was used to extend internal storage died. Now the apps I moved there are also gone. I don't remember precisely what I had on the card but would like to reinstall all of them.

After doing factory reset on my phones, the system automatically installs my previously installed apps after logging in to my google account. Is there a way to access this list?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - your installation history is preserved in the Google Play Account associated with your device.  To see your apps, both current and previously installed, you can navigate to the Play Store App -> My Apps and Games (in the drawer) -> Library on your device.

Alternatively, you can visit https://play.google.com/apps?hl=en_US

Please note that if you side loaded apps or installed from a third-party store, the above information does not apply.